# Grails SpringSecurityService: Cannot get property 'principal' on null object

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm writing an update or change user data form in Grails. This is a part of my form, where user can change his old login:

```
<g:form class="form-signin" controller="VisitorSpace">
    <label for="login" class="sr-only">Логин</label>
    <g:textField id="login" class="form-control" name="login" placeholder="Логин" value="${springSecurityService.principal.username}" required="" autofocus=""/>
...
</g:form>
```

Old user data must be shown before update. I use for it: `${springSecurityService.principal.username}`
But when I run this page I get such error:

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error
URI:/restorator/visitorSpace/editPrivateDataClass:java.lang.NullPointerExceptionMessage:Cannot get property 'principal' on null object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that to work you would have had to have passed the `springSecurityService` to the GSP via its model. You can use `applicationContext.springSecurityService` to extract it from the context if you don't want to pass it in, or use the taglib instead of the service.